# Palette library not returning color code which i want. why?

Tags: android, android-palette

I have created an application which first capture an image then apply color of vibrant palette to text.

Here is my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent c = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(c,0);
            }
        });
    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        if (imageBitmap != null && !imageBitmap.isRecycled()) {
            Palette palette = Palette.from(imageBitmap).generate();
            Palette.PaletteAsyncListener paletteAsyncListener = new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
                    int defaultColor = 0x000000;
                    int vibrant = palette.getVibrantColor(defaultColor);
                    tv.setTextColor(vibrant);
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

However, this code doesn't change color of my `textview`.

When I try to print that integer it returns long number, do you know what is wrong?